# Convergence and acceptance rate in MCMC

Tags: simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence

I am trying to fit a cubeoid to data approximately containing one (or many) 2D sigmoids using MCMC. Assuming trying to fit one model cuboid, it has 5 parameters: position, size and height.
$$\theta = \{x,y,dx,dy,h\}$$

[image: 2D sigmoid]

My likelihood function is assumed to be inversely proportional to the absolute height difference between data and model. Due to all parameters being positive my proposed parameter is a lognormal distribution with $\mu_i=\log(\theta_i)$ for $i=1,...,5$. I have also tried my likelihood being $\exp(-\Delta z)$ where $\Delta z$ is the sum of the absolute height differences with no improvement.

With a small variance my acceptance ratio is close to one all the time, meaning that my algorithm is almost always accepting my proposed parameters.
With larger variances the algorithm makes jumps around the parameter space without converging to place the cuboid in approximately the right place on **one** of the sigmoids in the data.

**How should I change my likelihood function or variances to make the algorithm converge?**

EDIT, additional information in matlab syntax.
My variances:

```
variances = [0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.01];
```

Two of the tried likelihoods, where datasz is the size of data matrix in each dimension and the parameters is in the same order as $\theta$ above.
Of course only one of the l is used at the time.

```
yvec = round(parameters(2)-parameters(4):parameters(2)+parameters(4));
xvec = round(parameters(1)-parameters(3):parameters(1)+parameters(3));
l = datasz(1) * datasz(2) / sum(sum(abs(data-model)));
% or
l = 1/(2*sum(sum(abs(data(yvec,xvec)-model(yvec,xvec))))/(parameters(3)*parameters(4)*4) - (parameters(3)*parameters(4)*4)^0.1);
```

My proposal distribution is lognormal and random('logn', $\mu$,$\sigma$) generates one sample from the lognormal distribution with $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

```
param(1) = random('logn', log(parameters(1)), variances(1));
```

EDIT2, psuedo algorithm with data $D$.

1. initalize $\theta_i$ giving model $M_i$.
2. propose new parameters $\theta_p$ giving model $M_p$
3. calculate likelihood: $l = \frac{1}{|D-M|}$ for $i$ and $p$.
4. acceptance ratio by $\alpha = min\{1, \frac{l_{p}}{l_{i}}\}$
5. if $u < \alpha$ keep the proposed parameters $\theta_{i+1}:=\theta_p$, otherwize use the old parameters $\theta_{i+1}:=\theta_i$.

Comment: This is the first time I see someone proposing to change the likelihood to fit the MCMC algorithm rather than the opposite! The goal is to target the posterior, not to target the algorithm.

Comment: @Xi'an: My problem is that the algorithm doesn't converge, and my posterior is known and can be sampled, see the image. What do you mean by targeting the posterior?

Comment: @Xi'an: I have updated with some info about likelihood. The image is the available posterior/data which is a 2D sigmoid (in reality there is noise which I am disregarding here) which I have a priori knowledge about being a cubeoid. I am therefore trying to find the "best parameters" that fit the cubeoid to the sigmoid in some sense. I have therefore one variance for each parameter.

Comment: @Xi'an: added some psuedo code to explain my reasoning as well.

Comment: Do you scale the variances against the acceptance rates? In order to achieve an average acceptance of 25%.

Comment: @Xi'an: What do you mean with scale? Should I adapt it during the algorithm running or beforehand? I haven't been able to manually find a variance where it does converge and doesn't have a average accept ratio of 1.